# Performance improvement: Finding the number of unique rows that end with a specific string (for each row in the dataframe)?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

**Problem:**
I have a pandas dataframe ("df" in the code below) with ~1M rows.
One of the columns contains seemingly random strings.

|  | column_A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | f24g5.eegajk.cae |
| 2 | gwee.wdegsugew |
| 3 | **43fsf5** |
| 4 | gefae.**43fsf5** |
| ... | ... |
| 10234 | w4.t4w.**43fsf5** |
| ... | ... |
| 150968 | gefae.**43fsf5** |

I want to find the number of unique strings that are a substring of (precisely: that end with) another string (row). Afterward, I want to count these unique occurrences.

**Example:**
In the example above one can find the string "43fsf5" in line 3. This very string can also be found at the end of the strings in lines 4, 10234, and 150968. But since the strings in lines 4 and 150968 are identical, the number of unique (found) strings is 2. This value should be added to a new column ("column_B") in row 4. I know that each substring I am looking for will have a leading '.' (dot) (that is not part of the substring itself).

**Working (but inefficient?) solution:**

```
def my_func(s):
    return df[df.column_A.str.endswith(f'.{s}')].column_A.nunique()

df["column_B"] = df.column_A.apply(my_func)
```

but this code runs for around 1 hour.
Besides multiprocessing, how could one improve the speed of this computation?
(e.g. by applying groupby in a clever way?).

Edit: Typo in my_func code

Comment: for clarification: I want to count the unique strings for EVERY row in the dataset. the example above is just for a SINGLE row (#3).

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your dataset is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column_A": ["f24g5.eegajk.cae", "43fsf5", "gefae.43fsf5",
            "w4.t4w.43fsf5", "gefae.43fsf5"]})
```

And your searched string is `43fsf5`:

```
s = ".43fsf5"
df[f"endswith_{s}"] = df.column_A.str.endswith(s)
df.loc[(df[f"endswith_{s}"])]["column_A"].unique() # unique values with condition True
df.loc[(df[f"endswith_{s}"])]["column_A"].nunique() # number of unique values with condition True
```

***Testing***

Generating a random df with 10.100.000  rows with 100.000 which ends with `.43fsf5` (mean length of the string is 20):

```
def random_string(
    length : int 
) -> str:
    base = string.punctuation + string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choices(base, k=length))

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"column_A": 
         [random_string(19) + ".43fsf5" for _ in range(10**5)] + \
         [random_string(19) for _ in range(10**7)]})
```

Using timeit ***(2.69 s ± 27.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)***:

```
%%timeit
df[f"endswith_{s}"] = df.column_A.str.endswith(s)
df.loc[(df[f"endswith_{s}"])]["column_A"].nunique()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now this is the result for ".43fsf5". But I want the result for every (!) row value. So starting with row 1: I need to find (and count) all unique rows that end with ".cae", for row 2 find (and count) all unique rows with ".wdegsugew", and so on ... . It is exactly this "nesting" that makes the whole procedure so awfully slow. But for me it feel like there could be some tricky group-by workaround?

Comment: Maybe there is a solution with regex and groupby. If you share your dataset with drive  I'll see what I can do.

Comment: thanks for the offer of going that length! [here a link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6mo8wps8og23ape/samples.pkl?dl=0) to the pickled pandas dataframe from my dropbox. I included the results I would expect. I computed them with the code I posted above and it took around 25s (for a sample size of 10.000).